# How to insert file data in blob column in sqlite using terminal

Tags: sqlite, file, terminal, insert

I have following table in Sqlite :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Articles" (
    "id"    integer NOT NULL,
    "name"  varchar NOT NULL,
    "post_date" date DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "last_edit_date"    date,
    "html"  blob NOT NULL,
    "css"   blob,
    "js"    blob,
    CONSTRAINT "Articles_pk" PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
```

I've been using GUI "DB Browser for SQLite" for inserting values and copypasting contents of files into html,css and js columns but now I want to know How can I do this with terminal without GUI using `insert` command

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://sqlite.org/cli.html#file_i_o_functions). I have to use the `readfile()` function.